# Save List as JSON array in postgresql

Tags: java, json, postgresql, hibernate

I have a List `private List<Lesson> lessons;` and I need to save this list to PostgreSQL database column with data type `_json` or `json[]` (JSON array). But I get one of these errors:

> ERROR: column "lessons" is of type json[] but the expression is of
>   type character varying`or`ERROR: malformed array literal:
>   "[{"id":17,"title":"Lesson 1","part":1.0}]

How correctly serialize `List` to get the correct format of Postgresql JSON array?

Comment: Can you update the question what you tried so far?

Comment: @DumiduUdayanga I tried using ObjectMapper and Gson library

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use `JsonBinaryType` class from `com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types` library and apply `json` (or `jsonb`) to the column definition:

```
// LessonList.java
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;

@Entity
@Table(name = "lessons")
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class LessonList {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
    private List<Lesson> lessons;
}
```

SQL Script to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE "lessons" (
   "id" Serial NOT NULL,
   "lessons" JSON NOT NULL,
   "created_at" Timestamp Without Time Zone DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

The rest of the classes are to provide working example:

```
// Lesson.java
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Lesson {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private double part;
}
```

---

A repository extending Spring `CrudRepository` interface and DAO class are trivial.

A command line runner to run test:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class TestJson implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private LessonListDao dao;

    @Override
    public void run(String[] args) {

        List<Lesson> lessons = Arrays.asList(
                Lesson.builder().id(11).title("Physics").part(1.0).build(),
                Lesson.builder().id(12).title("Chemistry").part(2.0).build(),
                Lesson.builder().id(13).title("Biology").part(3.0).build()
        );

        LessonList list = LessonList.builder().lessons(lessons).build();

        LessonList result = dao.save(list);

        LOGGER.info("result: " + result);

        List<LessonList> all = dao.findAll();
        all.forEach(a -> LOGGER.info("item #" + a.getId() + "; lessons=" + a.getLessons()));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
lesson.TestJson     : result: lesson.LessonList@6166aac5
lesson.TestJson     : item #1; lessons=[Lesson(id=1, title=Math, part=1.0), Lesson(id=2, title=English, part=2.0), Lesson(id=3, title=Informatics, part=3.0)]
lesson.TestJson     : item #2; lessons=[Lesson(id=11, title=Physics, part=1.0), Lesson(id=12, title=Chemistry, part=2.0), Lesson(id=13, title=Biology, part=3.0)]
```

DB Data: `SELECT * FROM "public".lessons`:

```
**id**          **lessons**                                     **created_at**
[PK] Integer    json                                            timestamp without timezone
1               [{"id":1,"title":"Math","part":1.0},            2020-06-03 18:08:55.948007
                {"id":2,"title":"English","part":2.0},
                {"id":3,"title":"Informatics","part":3.0}]
2               [{"id":11,"title":"Physics","part":1.0},        2020-06-03 18:27:06.565191
                {"id":12,"title":"Chemistry","part":2.0},
                {"id":13,"title":"Biology","part":3.0}]
```

**Update**

This library does not support `json[]` type because it could be rather redundant.

The example below uses plain `JDBC + ObjectMapper` to handle specific PostgreSQL array of `json`
Main point is that you need to use `getArray` method of `ResultSet` and then convert the String values inside `PGobject` to your object

```
ConfigurableEnvironment environment = (ConfigurableEnvironment) applicationContext.getEnvironment();
DataSource ds = DataSourceBuilder.create()
.username(environment.getProperty("ds.pgsql.username"))
.password(environment.getProperty("ds.pgsql.password"))
.url(environment.getProperty("ds.pgsql.url")).build();

try (Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id, lessons FROM lesson");
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            Object[] arrLessons = (Object[]) rs.getArray("lessons").getArray();

            List<Lesson> jsonLessons = Arrays.stream(arrLessons)
                                             .map(PGobject.class::cast)
                                             .map(lesson -> convert(lesson.getValue()))
                                             .collect(Collectors.toList());

            System.out.println(id + "; converted: " + jsonLessons);
        }
}
//...
private Lesson convert(String value) {
    try {
        return mapper.readValue(value, Lesson.class);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
}
```

Output

```
1; converted: [Lesson(id=1, title=Math, part=0.0), Lesson(id=2, title=English, part=0.0)]
2; converted: [Lesson(id=3, title=Physics, part=0.0), Lesson(id=4, title=Chemistry, part=0.0)]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I tried this solution and not works with column type JSON array(Postgresql json[]). Your solution can be applied to column JSON, not JSON array

Comment: JSON array `json[]` is not supported with this library.  You may check the update with the specific fix.